# How to call a MSSQL stored procedure using java

Tags: java, sql-server

i had few doubts which need clarification. Please help me to get through

i had a stored procedure in my MSSQL Server and i need to call it from java, as per my knowledge i need to perform these steps to call the procedure

1. connect to the database(exact location where the procedure is stored)
2. call the procedure using callablestatement
    `CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call getEmployeeDetails(?, ?)}");`

Know please give me examples on how to use callablestatement and also how to pass parameters to procedures using java.

Comment: googling would give you nice tutorials on JDBC, right?

Comment: @BhaveshShah The link you posted is the link to the question i asked just now :) Please give me another link :) mean while i will try googling it

Comment: Sorry @Trini. Actually I pasted it by mistakely. Forgive me for that. The Link I want to paste is : http://www.javadb.com/connect-to-database-and-call-stored-procedure

Comment: @BhaveshShah Thanks that information is helpful to me. please keep a eye on my question because i will edit my question or ask for more details regarding this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/*After Establishing the connection to MSSQL database, here goes the code how to call a stored procedure*/

```
 Connection conn;
 CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.usp_scr_getAllFiles()}");
 stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call dbo.usp_scr_startLoading()}");   
 stmt.close();
 conn.close();
```

/*In the above code i called two stored procedures*/